# BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv

I have installed pyenv and was trying to install python, however am continuing to get build failed error and am not sure how to fix it.

Tried taking these steps but am still getting the same error

- STEP 1: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
- STEP 2: `xcode-select --install`
- STEP 3: `pyenv install 3.8.5`

Still got the same error as before:

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.5...
patching file 'Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst'
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/3q/f7sgq3p54sx7_3tk6d251wz00000gr/T/python-build.20240304113743.14799
Results logged to /var/folders/3q/f7sgq3p54sx7_3tk6d251wz00000gr/T/python-build.20240304113743.14799.log
```

Last 10 log lines:

```
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
checking size of pthread_key_t... 8
checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... no
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my **Apple MacOS Sonama 14.4**:

### Solution

This is what worked for me:

```bash
PYTHON_BUILD_HOMEBREW_OPENSSL_FORMULA=openssl@1.1 arch -x86_64 pyenv install 3.12.2
```

### Context

- I used Apple migration assistant to move from my Apple Intel based to the Apple M1 Max
- My **Terminal** is running on `arm64` while my `brew` command is running on `x86_64`

### Two main issues:

#### 1) Regarding chip `arch` between `x86_64` and `arm64`

Even if I'm running my terminal in `arm64`, which I can verify by running `arch` command with the following result:

```bash
$ arch
arm64
```

Homebrew `brew` command is still running in `x86_64` through `Rosetta 2` on the terminal.

You can check this by running `brew config`:

```bash
brew config

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.2.14
...
macOS: 14.4-x86_64
...
Xcode: 15.3
Rosetta 2: true
```

With that information, it makes it easier to figure out which dependencies need to be installed and for which target chip architecture (`arm64` or `x86_64`).

#### 2) Openssl version and `libb2`

I ran into the following issue: `ERROR:root:code for hash blake2s was not found`

You might need to install `libb2` for the target `arch`

Example:

```bash
arch -arm64 brew install libb2
```

This is also the reason why I'm specifying `openssl@1.1` on the installation command.

### Other resources

You can find more detailed information here:

- [pyenv-issue-1669-comment-2016319801](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1669#issuecomment-2016319801)
- [libb2 installation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1529#issuecomment-1805234651)

I hope this helps.